# Avoiding the facebook login webform on startup

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am pretty much using the samples in the SDK for my app. And it works great. Except I have two questions, relating to authentication.
1. How can I avoid the webform from popping up each time I start up the app? Once I have authorized my app, each time I restart it, I see the webform appear for a second and then it closes. Not very clean, in my opinion. Is there a way to check if I am still logged in, and have given my app authorization before displaying the webform?
2. If I become unauthenticated while my app is running, is there a way for me to easily detect that and then show the login form again?

I think I am close with my code below, but not quite there.

Thanks in advance!

```
private string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "read_stream", "offline_access" };

public Form1()
{
    var fbLoginDialog = new FacebookLoginDialog(AppId, extendedPermissions);

    //always shows login dialog, even if the app was just recently closed. Is this necessary?
    fbLoginDialog.ShowDialog(); 

    //every minute look for new posts
    clockTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(clockTimer_Elapsed); 

    DisplayAppropriateMessage(fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult);
    GetAllData(unixTimeOfNewestPost);
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void DisplayAppropriateMessage(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
{
  if (facebookOAuthResult != null)
  {
    if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
    {
      _accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show(facebookOAuthResult.ErrorDescription);
    }
  }
}

private void GetAllData(double unixTs)
{
  var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
  Facebook.JsonArray posts = new JsonArray();
  try
  {
      var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me/home?since=" + unixTs + "&limit=1000");
      posts = (Facebook.JsonArray)result["data"];
  }
  catch (FacebookOAuthException e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("FacebookOAuthException", 
      "Facebook Authorization problem. The error message was '" + e.Message + "'.", null, "");
    //show the login form again???
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Log("Exception. There was a general exception. The error message was '" + e.Message + "'.");
  }

  foreach (Facebook.JsonObject post in posts)
  {
    // do stuff with each post
  }
} // end of GetPosts()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.How can I avoid the webform from popping up each time I start up the app? Once I have authorized my app, each time I restart it, I see the webform appear for a second and then it closes. Not very clean, in my opinion. Is there a way to check if I am still logged in, and have given my app authorization before displaying the webform?

**You will need to save the access token safely somewhere else. Incase you have that access token you don't need to even ask for the login dialog.**

2.If I become unauthenticated while my app is running, is there a way for me to easily detect that and then show the login form again?

**You will need to catch FacebookOAuthException to every requests you make and then ask the user to login**